# CloudFormation AWS::Events::Rule: Encountered unsupported property Id

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

Trying to create AWS Lambda Function using CloudFormation. When creating schedule rule as target for the AWS Lambda Function I'm getting the following error:

> Lambda function needs targets

My template looks like:

```json
"ScheduledRule": {
    "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
    "Properties": {
        "Description": "ScheduledRule",
        "ScheduleExpression": "rate(10 minutes)",
        "State": "ENABLED",
        "Targets": [{
            "Arn": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaFunction", "Arn"]
            }

        }],

        "Id": "id",
        "RoleArn": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "LambdaFunction",
                "Arn"
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Could you please add your complete template and the error message to your question?

Answer (score 1):

The nesting of your event rule is wrong. In your template `Id` and `RoleArn` are children of `Properties`, whereas they should be children of your target. A correct template would be:

```json
"ScheduledRule": {
    "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
    "Properties": {
        "Description": "ScheduledRule",
        "ScheduleExpression": "rate(10 minutes)",
        "State": "ENABLED",
        "Targets": [{
            "Arn": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaFunction", "Arn"]
            },
            "Id": "id",
            "RoleArn": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "LambdaFunction",
                    "Arn"
                ]
            }
        }]
    }
},
```